# Can I pass a parameter to ES6 generator function

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

Here's a ES6 generator:

```
function *Gen() {
    var input1 = yield 'output1'
}

var gen = Gen()

gen.next('input1').value // return 'output1'
```

gen called 1st time, return `output1` but the variable `input1` doesn't equal `'input1'` which passed in , the value of `input` actually is the 'input2', 2nd time `next('input2')`called

My question is how to access the `input1` which is the first time next called, something like:

```
function *Gen() {
    var input 1 = param1
    var input2 = yield 'output1'
}
```

Comment: Well-known problem. The usual solution is to yield a dummy initial value which is thrown away, but servers to "seed" the generator.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you obtain the generator you don't have `yield`s you can push value to (you are at the beginning of the generator function). You need to trigger the generator and reach the first `yield` by calling `gen.next()` without any arguments. At this point you have an `yield` at your disposal and you can push your value via `gen.next('input1')` effectively replacing the expression `yield 'output1'` with the value you passed to `next` - 'input1'. Then you need another `yield` or a `return` to provide your custom value to the consumer of the generator. Here is the code:

```
function *Gen() {
    var input1 = yield 'output1'
    return input1
}

var gen = Gen()

gen.next();
gen.next('input1').value // return 'input1'
```

Comment: `When you obtain the generator you don't have yields you can push value to (you are at the beginning of the generator function)` +1

Answer (score 7):

[This](http://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators) great article about generator answered my question, input1 has been tossed away, there's no way to access it. It's weird but true

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the article to your answer, otherwise If the link goes down it won't hold any value anymore.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's simply this example:

```js
function *createGenerator(input) {
    yield input
}

var generator = createGenerator('input')

console.log(
    generator
    .next()
    .value
)
// input
```

So you can pass a value into the generator on creation and pull it out, but if you've already created the generator, the only way to get a value in is by passing it through `.next`. But which `.next`?

```js
function *createGenerator() {
    const input = yield
    yield input
}

var generator = createGenerator()

console.log(
    generator
    .next('input1')
    .value
)
// undefined

console.log(
    generator
    .next('input2')
    .value
)
// input2
```

As you can see in this example, the first input doesn't come through, but the second does. That's because your code executes in a generator up to the first `yield` and then stops. Because of that, the first value you pass in will be missing because there's no code to evaluate it.

Let's look at another example:

```js
function *createGenerator() {
    const input1 = yield
    const input2 = yield input1
    yield input2
}

var generator = createGenerator()

console.log(
    generator
    .next('input0')
    .value
)
// undefined

console.log(
    generator
    .next('input1')
    .value
)
// input1

console.log(
    generator
    .next('input2')
    .value
)
// input2

console.log(
    generator
    .next('input3')
    .value
)
// undefined
```

When you call `.next` the second time, you evaluate the value passed in, and keep processing code until the next `yield`. In this case, you execute `yield input`, but nothing to the left of it because that's technically the "next line" of execution in JavaScript's AST.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a parametrised generator function you can use a higher order function that returns generator:

```
function myGenerator(startFrom) {
    return (function *() {
        var i = startFrom;
        while (true) yield i++;
    })();
}

var gen = myGenerator(5);
console.log(gen.next().value) // 5
console.log(gen.next().value) // 6
console.log(gen.next().value) // 7
```

Higher order generators can be of use too:

```
function getGenerator(baseStartFrom, expStartFrom) {
    return (function *() {
        var a = baseStartFrom;
        while (true) {
          yield (function *() {
              var i = expStartFrom;
              while (true) yield Math.pow(a, i++);
          })();
          a++;
        }
    })();
}

var gen = getGenerator(2, 3);
var gen2 = gen.next().value; // generator yields powers of 2
  console.log(gen2.next().value); // 8
  console.log(gen2.next().value); // 16
  console.log(gen2.next().value); // 32
var gen3 = gen.next().value; // generator yields powers of 3
  console.log(gen3.next().value); // 27
  console.log(gen3.next().value); // 81
  console.log(gen3.next().value); // 243
```

The sample is most likely useless but the same approach can be used, for example, to generate random number generators.

Comment: Huh? That's not a higher-order function. And could be replaced by the trivial `function* myGenerator(i) { while (true) yield i++; }`

Comment: @Bergi you can indeed :) Somehow I thought you cannot. Thanks. What's wrong with "higher-order" term?

Comment: To me, neither of your generators matches the definition of [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)

Comment: doesn't return functions indeed... probably did originally.

Comment: i upvoted this -- it's awesome and was exactly what i needed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to generate a random number by passing the max value it should return.

```
function *GenerateRandomNumber(maxNo){
    while(true){
        yield Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNo);
    }
}

let randomGenerator = GenerateRandomNumber(10);
randomGenerator.next().value; // A random Number between 0 - 9
```